# Grails application with offline storage/querying capabilities

Tags: grails, web-applications

I have a friend who wants me to write an inventory management system for the three stores he owns. I was thinking I could write a webapp using Grails such that all three stores can read from and write to a common database. The problem is that in case there is a problem with the internet connection, he'll lose connection the the DB and therefore won't be able to make any transactions.

My question is that in case of a network failure can I do something which will make the application fall back to a local DB instance and when the network is back up, reconnect and update the data in the main DB?

Comment: You might be able to use MongoDB (see the Mongodb plugin) and have each Grails instance write to its own Mongo instance (? or maybe have a single master and 2 slaves?) with replication happening. If one node loses its connection it should continue to use its local Mongo node (closest node?) until the other nodes come back up. I haven't done anything like this so not 100% sure it will work for your use case but its worth a look.

Comment: The machines with the webapps will be in different geographic locations. I don't think this model is going to work for me.

Comment: I don't believe that different geographic locations should be an issue - in fact it is designed to handle this as you often want an offsite slave to be able to take over as Master if there is a power/network/vulnerability issue in one data centre.

Comment: Oh, I'll look into it then. But isn't MongoDB designed for Bid Data. My data is not going to span more than a couple of GBs at most.

Comment: i don't think that mongo db is designed for big data per se. Of course, with horizontal scaling, that a lot of nosql stores allow you to do easily, you can achieve scenarions where you have some kind of "big data". But the reasons, why you want to scale horizontal could be of other form (like the scenario you described). So @nickdos hint here seems to be a valid approach.

Answer (score 0):

Push responsibility to the level of DB and use master-master replication. Mysql for example offers such thing. Still, it can be hard with stock for example.

Comment: I don't think my question is related to master-master replication.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `JMS-plugin` for your scenario. You app dumps data into the queue, and the latter handles the rest. You can specify re-try strategy for example.